# magento 1.9 not redirecting to success page..

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

Magento 1.9 not redirecting to success page after placing order. 
When i am going to sales -> order then i can see that order is saved there.. 
I have php_mbstring already enabled..

[image]

My php version is 7. 
Any idea what is going wrong??

Comment: Have you enable magento log ,Please check log files

Comment: There is nothing in log file

Comment: any idea?? what ca be the problem

Comment: Magento 1 is not compatible with PHP7 out of the box, youneed to install `Inchoo_PHP7` module to make your Magento 1.9 compatible with PHP7, have you done that ?

Comment: No. Tell me how can i get that

Comment: I just install https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7 module .. but problem is not solved

Comment: disable all third party module and try .